# Value inside array changes after an if statement?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why in my if statement returns the value 1 after an if statement is completed.

```
        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("SELECT id, username, managedby, commisionPercentage FROM `accounts` WHERE id = '$studentSignedUpBy'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

        if ($results[0]['commisionPercentage'] =! 0 ) {
            $agentCommisionPercentage = $results[0]['commisionPercentage'];
            $commisiontype = 2;
        }
       echo $results[0]['managedby']; //this returns the correct value (25)
         if ($results[0]['managedby'] =! 0 ) {
             $managedStudentSignedUp = $results[0]['managedby'];
         } 
         echo $results[0]['managedby']; //this returns the value 1 which ends up making $managedstudentSignedUp = 1 which is an issue.
```

Comment: It's `!=` not `=!`

Comment: NOT EQUAL, not EQUAL NOT    ` if ($results[0]['managedby'] != 0 ) {`

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you very much! I need more coffee this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
if ($results[0]['managedby'] =! 0 ) {
```

Broken down this is *assigning* the opposite value of 0 (falsy), which is boolean true. When you `echo` it the type is juggled and output as an integer which is 1.

Obviously you want to use `!=` instead for comparison rather than assignment.

Comment: Thank you, I clearly needed more coffee this morning!

Answer (score 0):

problem with if condition operator 
its not 
`=!` it will be `!=` 
check details here

[Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)